# How to recalculate the price of a bundle product based on a value in a textfield in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.1.7, bundle

I created a bundle product and placed two input fields on the page for the user to input length and width. I would like to calculate a value and let set options of the bundled product depending on the input:

if calculation = 2 --> Choose option 1
if calculation = 3 --> Choose option 2

Two questions: 
a. Where to find the Javascript that calculates the bundle? 
b. Is this the best way or is there an other solution besides Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for a.:

Open (or copy) this file:  app/design/frontend/Custom/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Bundle/Layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

Write the following in the HEAD-section:

```
<link src="js/konfigurator.js"/>
```

The konfigurator.js should be placed in: 
app/design/frontend/Custom/YOUR_THEME/web/js